# CSS horizontal menu not clearing because I need postion absolute

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

EDIT: in theory i think i could accomplish this by having a dummy ul between the 2 level and then positioning the 'second (now 3rd) level. Crude proof of concept > http://jsfiddle.net/petergus/jk7vU/

I have a horizontal dropdown menu that I am trying to get to stretch its parent div height.
The problem I run into is the child `ul`. In order to get it to sit on a line below the main menu I have to use `position: absolute` but that takes it out of the flow.

Is it even possible to have a multilevel horizontal list without set container height?

EDIT: Here is an illustration screenshot of what i am trying to accomplish. EXCEPT the content (black text behind) should slide down.

[image]

Here is how the content slides down >

[image: this is showing how the content below slides down]

as far as i can tell this is simple a problem of `position: relative` vs `absolute`

Please see a sample setup at http://jsfiddle.net/petergus/nC32t/

HTML:

```
<div class="mnavwrapper">

   <div id="mnav">

    <ul class="menu clearfix">
        <li class="first expanded">
            <span title="" class="nolink">Click me here</span>
            <ul class="submenu clearfix">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">consultancy</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">daylight</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">solutions</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">design</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">something</a></li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="#team" title="">team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expanded"><span title="" class="nolink">portfolio</span>
            <ul class="submenu clearfix">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="http://dev.manss.co#" title="">all projects</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">commercial</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">public</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">private</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">something</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="expanded"><span title="" class="nolink">another</span>
            <ul class="submenu clearfix">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">techniques </a></li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">influences</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>                    

</div>
</div>


<div id="contentbody">
 <p>Hello text</p>
</div>
```

​CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

ul.menu {
/*display: inline-block;*/
list-style: none;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
display: block;
    position:relative;
}
ul.menu li {
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: inline;
}
ul.menu li {
float: left;
}
 ul.submenu {
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
 }
 ul.submenu li {
     float: left;
 }

.mnavwrapper {
    /*clear: both;*/
}
#mnav {
    background: lightblue;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 100%;

}
#contentbody {
    background: pink;
}
p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

​jQuery:

```
$('.active-trail').addClass('selected');


$('ul.menu .nolink').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected').end().next('ul').slideToggle().parent().siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(150).parent().removeClass('selected');
});​
```

Comment: why not make several ULs instead of nested ULs?

Comment: Next time, please make your question "self-contained" by also including the code.  Otherwise, when the jsFiddle link goes dead, it's useless.

Comment: thanks Sparky, will do :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
          http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>test doc</title>

    <style type="text/css">

      ul {
      display: table;
      padding: 0;
      }

      li {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 13em;
      }

      li li {
      display: none;
      width: auto;
      }

      li:hover li {
      display: inline-block;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>dfhg</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Hover here for sub-menu
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">daylight</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">team</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Yet another sub-menu
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">daylight</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">team</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <p>Hello text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

cheers,

gary

Comment: thanks, thats quite close any very nice! only thing is its to be a flexible design so fixed widths is tricky.
probably im asking for to much heh!

Answer (score 0):

something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/DDeRT/

html:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li class="nav1">nav
        <ul>
            <li>sub</li>
            <li>sub</li>
            <li>sub</li>
            <li>sub</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav2">nav2
        <ul>
            <li>sub</li>
            <li>sub</li>
            <li>sub</li>
            <li>sub</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.nav > ul >li{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
}
.nav1{
    left: 50px;
}
.nav2{
    left: 100px;
}
.nav > ul >li > ul > li{
    display: none;
}
.nav > ul >li:hover > ul > li{
    display: inline;
}
​
```

Comment: That's interesting but it still doesn't for the content to bump down below it. It seems its really not possible to have a multi level horizontal menu without absolute positioning.